# React-Redux- Delete an item from list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Currently I am working on this FCC project:
https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-a-recipe-box

As of now, I was able to implement on adding new recipes to the list.

However, I am having hard to implement on how to edit/delete per each recipe item list. For now, I just want to focus on how to DELETE per item.

The way I am displaying the recipe list is in the RecipeBox Container, where I am using map function to iteratively rendering each of them from the app's state, as well as rendering the buttons EDIT and DELETE.

But I cant seem to attach an action to it. 
I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

RecipeBox Container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem, Panel, Button, Modals } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { deleteRecipe } from '../actions/index';

class RecipeBox extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };

  }
  renderRecipeList(recipeItem,index){
    const recipe = recipeItem.recipe;
    const ingredients = recipeItem.ingredients;
    return(
      <div key={index}>
        <Panel bsStyle="primary" collapsible header={<h3>{recipe}</h3>}>
          <ListGroup >
            <ListGroupItem  header="Ingredients"></ListGroupItem>
            {ingredients.map(function(ingredient,index){
              return <ListGroupItem key={index}>{ingredient}</ListGroupItem>;
            })}
            <ListGroupItem>
              <Button
                onClick={this.props.deleteRecipe(recipeItem)}
                bsStyle="danger">Delete
              </Button>
              <Button
                onClick={() => console.log('EDIT!')}
                bsStyle="info">Edit
              </Button>
            </ListGroupItem>
          </ListGroup>
        </Panel>
      </div>
    )
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className='panel-group'>
          {this.props.addRecipe.map(this.renderRecipeList)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    addRecipe : state.addRecipe
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({deleteRecipe}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(RecipeBox);
```

This seems very trivial, but I keep hitting a roadblock..

Comment: can you show us your reducer code, so that we can check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `this.renderRecipeList = this.renderRecipeList.bind(this)` in the constructor.

Comment: Oops, forgot about binding it..Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

```
 render(){
 return(
  <div className="container">
    <div className='panel-group'>
      {this.props.addRecipe.map(this.renderRecipeList.bind(this))}
    </div>
  </div>
 )
}
```